# K -> 2 tape reduction for nondeterministic Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism, simulation, tape-complexity

How to I show that any language in NTIME(T(n)) can be accepted by a non-deterministic 2-tape O(T(n)) time-bounded Turing machine, with modifiable input tape?

I've seen the k to 2 tape reduction for deterministic Turing machines, which increase the running time by a logarithmic factor, but I'm not sure if I can modify that to help me prove the above statement.

Comment: See the hint on Lance Fortnow's blog: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/03/tape-reduction.html. After you successfully solve the exercise, you can summarize the solution as an answer to your own question.